# spring security 3: sick and tired. can anyone copy a simple project including JARS

Tags: spring-security

I have wasted more than 5 hours in analyzing the error  **Configuration problem: You cannot use a spring-security-2.0.xsd schema with Spring Security 3.0. Please update your schema declarations to the 3.0 schema.**

tried so many different versions of jars

nothing worked out

I am literally helpless..

PLS CAN ANYONE COPY A SAMPLE SPRING SECURITY 3 PROJECT including the jars??

i thank you

Comment: You should atleast post what you have tried so far. Also how you are importing the jars into your project whether you are using any dependency management tool like Ivy or Maven ..etc

Comment: i used neither ant nor maven,
i used the run option available in eclipse. I downloaded the code from roseindia.net

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you have mess in your jars and xml configuration. I bet you have something like

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security 
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd
    ">
  <!-- stuff here -->
</beans:beans>
```

in your security-context.xml, and you are using older version of Spring Security (i.e. 3.0) while the above configuration requires version 3.0.3. Please be sure, that all `spring-security-XXX-YYY.jar`s are in the same version (especially check the presense of `spring-security-config`), and update your schema to appropriate version, which you define in this line:

```
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd
```

Answer (score 0):

http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.xsd solved same problem I was facing in my code. +1 @Xaerxess.